# Does Javascript equal sign reference objects or clones them?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, object-reference

In `MyApp.something.BigObject` I have a memory expensive object and I like to do this `var theObject = MyApp.something.BigObject;`. My question is would that take up double the memory or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: thanks for that, I wasn't able to find it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "equals sign" is the assignment operator. If the RHS is an object, then a reference is assigned to the LHS, it does not clone or copy the object.

So given:

```
var obj = {};
var b = obj;
```

both *obj* and *b* reference the same object.