# Javascript getters and setters - why does it work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've come across the following code. It works, but I'm not sure why.

```
app.factory('myService', function() {
 var savedData = {}
 function set(data) {
   savedData = data;
 }
 function get() {
  return savedData;
 }

 return {
  set: set,
  get: get
 }

});
```

The function returns an object that consists of two functions, `set()` and `get()`. But it doesn't return the function itself, so why does it even work? Shouldn't the variable `savedData` go out of scope? Or should I think of `savedData` as of a variable allocated on heap with `new` keyword in Java? As long as my code has a reference to it somewhere, it doesn't cease to exist?

Comment: because factory returns an object which you returned from at the end `return {
  set: set,
  get: get
 }`

Comment: I know it returns that object. But my question is - how come the savedData variable is 'visible' from the user code?

Comment: Please read about [Closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: @user107986 also read up on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23683176/2435473

Comment: That is how Javascript works. It guarantees that local variables remain accesible. They only get deallocated when the garbage collector detects that no reference to it is possible.

Comment: You may also refer one of the most popular question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to dive deeper into JavaScript to understand it.
But i can briefly explain you:

1. `savedData` is defined at the same level as functions so they can use it inside from the `closure`.
2. functions are passed as a `reference`, so the pointer to function is copied and points to this function, even from another field.
3. The same with `return` statement: it can use `get` and `set` functions because they are in it's visibility scope.

Read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

[value type reference type object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480654/value-type-reference-type-object-in-javascript)