# What is difference between assigning value to variable and storing value into variable

Tags: javascript, oop

I was reading a book about object oriented javascript and I found this:

> Reference types do not store the object directly into the variable to which it is assigned, so the
>   object variable in this example doesn’t actually contain the object instance. Instead, it holds
>   a pointer (or reference) to the location in memory where the object exists. This is the primary
>   difference between objects and primitive values, as the primitive is stored directly in the variable.

My question is 
what is the meaning of this ?

**"Reference types do not store the object directly into the variable to which it is assigned, so the object variable in this example doesn’t actually contain the object instance." ??**

[image]

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: Updated my question! @Bergi

Comment: It says "in this example" - is there an example along side this block so an answer could explain using that example, rather than concocting a new one?  You should probably also attribute the book you are quoting from

Comment: Refer following post for reference [value type reference type object in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480654/value-type-reference-type-object-in-javascript)

Comment: they said "In this example" , But they didn't gave any @JamesThorpe :)

Comment: @mplungjan can you please give me the ebook link ? :( . I think i don't have  the correct book in my hand

Comment: Google your text - it is yellow in the book

Comment: :o :o , Oh my god!! thank you very much! Take a bow sir! :) @mplungjan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the image you provided you can see

```
var object1 = new Object();
var object2 = object1;
```

In this case, you have two variables that both store a reference (think of a pointer) to another place in your memory. In this place the object is stored. If you change your object via one of the references, and access it via the other one you will see it has changed.

```
object1.someVariable = 'asdf';
object2.someVariable = 'newValue';
console.log(object1.someVariable); // will give 'newValue'
console.log(object2.someVariable); // will also give 'newValue'
```

If you have scalar values, they will not store references, they will store the value itself.

Think of another example:

```
var primitiveString = 'asdf';
var anotherPrimitiveString = primitiveString;
```

Since both store the value it self, you can change one of the two strings, but the other one will still contain `asdf`, since they do not reference something.

```
anotherPrimitiveString = 'newValue';
console.log(primitiveString); // will give 'asdf'
console.log(anotherPrimitiveString); // will give 'newValue'
```

Here you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ub60dyk/) with the explained example.

Answer (score 2):

It could be clearer with an example:

```
var obj1 = { name: "John" };
var obj2 = obj1;
```

`obj1` and `obj2` point to the same location in memory.
It can be proved by changing `name` property:

```
obj2.name = "Bob";
console.log(obj1.name);  // "Bob"
```

Another behaviour with primitives:

```
var string1 = 'string';
var string2 = string1;
```

string1 and string2 point to different locations in memory. So changing `string2` won't affect `string1`

```
string2 = 'new string';
console.log(string1);  // 'string'
```

Comment: "string1 and string2 point to different locations in memory." - how do you know?

Comment: well, "obj2 = new object()" won't affect "obj1" as well.

Comment: Because they are not related. But if we assign your obj2 created with 'new Object()' to obj1 they'll start pointing to the same location in memory.

Comment: Your example doesn't prove that "string1 and string2 point to different locations in memory". Replace strings with objects and the result will be exactly the same.

Comment: @georg, could you please provide an example that will prove or refute a statement that string1 and string2 point to different locations in memory?

Comment: The point is, there's no "reference vs primitive" dichotomy in js, all types are references.

Answer (score 1):

You have a house. You = variable. House = value. Now, you have to prove you own that house. You get a paper, stating that you are the owner.

When you go around, you don't have to carry your house. You can just show people the paper.

House = heavy, hard to move.
Paper = small, light, easy to move.

That paper does what storing a reference does. It does not actually hold the real object, but it tells the rest of the system where it is.

Answer (score 1):

In computer science in general there is two type of variables types, pointers and values.
Pointers don't hold anything but an address so the computer can find where the real value is stored, while values store the real data.
The power of pointers is you can define one value and have multiple pointers use that same value. This is a huge gain in memory management and bidirectional communication from one section of code and another. 
This is an example of a pointer in javascript.

```
var foo = { value : 1};
var goo = foo;
goo.value = 4;
//now both goo.value and foo.value are both 4.
```

A value is something like this.

```
var foo = 2;
var goo = foo;
goo = 4;
//now foo is 2 and goo is 4.
```

Answer (score 1):

Object1 refers to some memory location (for example 2002). Object2 is also refered to the same memory location but by referring Object1.

Answer (score 1):

In js it is best to think that variables are pointers to objects & when assign directly to a variable you are not modifying any object , but pointing your variable to an object.

Let us take this example

```
var a= b ={}
```

So here `a` & `b` are pointer to same object.

Now set `a.someProp = 'value'`

it sets `b.someProp` as well since `a` & `b` point to same object

Where as storing a value in a variable is called `variable initialization`