# Why does splice() change both Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

Look at the following code:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3], y;
y = x;
y.splice(0,0,4);
```

which gives:

```
y = [4, 1, 2, 3]    //  (correct)

x = [4, 1, 2, 3]    //  (why did this change too?)
```

Why did the `x` array change when I called `.splice()` on `y`?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Answered pretty well by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480654/value-type-reference-type-object-in-javascript/

Comment: ok, so how do you keep x the same ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects (including arrays) are passed by reference (effectively, this is what it does... -- purists may disagree with this statement). The `splice` method mutates the original array. Therefore, since `x` and `y` point at the same array, a `splice` on `y` will change `x` as well. To do a shallow clone of `x` in to `y`, do `y = x.slice()`. (Note that any objects within `x` won't be cloned; they'll be passed by reference.)

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = a;
a[0] = 42;
alert(b[0]); // will show 42
var c = a.slice(); // explicitly makes a copy
a[1] = 6502;
alert(c[1]); // will show 2, not 6502
```

Taken from [value type reference type object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480654/value-type-reference-type-object-in-javascript/)